# Check array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js

For example I have an array:

```
reports = [
{comment:"asdasd", date:"13-02-2018", issueId:"1005"},
{comment:"asdasd", date:"14-02-2018", issueId:"1005"},
{comment:"asd123123asd", date:"14-02-2018", issueId:"1006"},
]
```

I don`t understand how to check if one issue (object) got a similar comment as it was yesterday - pass them to a new array.
In my case we see that issueId:"1005" got similar comments today and yesterday, so this two objects should go to new array (any new array).

Also I get today and yesterday date with moment.js like

```
 const today = moment().format('DD-MM-YYYY');
 const yesterday = moment().subtract(1, 'day').format('DD-MM-YYYY');
```

I am free to use ES5, ES6, underscore.js etc.
But I am stuck and don`t have an idea how to do this.

**EDIT**
similar comments in my case:
comment:'123123asd'
comment:'123123asd'
are similar.
Maybe it be clearer if I said that the main idea of all that "dancing" is next:
for example I got 2 empty arrays: one for objects from reports where "comment" of today and yesterday are similar, and another array - for objects where comments are similar for today, yesterday and day before yesterday

Comment: What is your definition of "similar comment"? Depending on that to figure out what is similar may take up a good deal of code.

Comment: Similar in my example is that issueId:1005, got comment:"asdasd" in 14.02.2018 and in 13.02.2018, so objects {comment:"asdasd", date:"13-02-2018", issueId:"1005"} and {comment:"asdasd", date:"14-02-2018", issueId:"1005"} should be pushed to new array.

Comment: Those comments are identical, so you would consider "asdasd" and "asdasb" as different?

Comment: @Dormilich yes "asdasd" and "asdasb" are different

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
let newArray = [];
for(let i = 0 ; i < reports.length ; i++){
    for(let x = 0 ; x < reports.length ; x++){
        if(i != x){
            if(reports[i].comment == reports[x].comment){
                newArray.push(reports[x])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it what you want ? Let me know if it helps you :)

Comment: Thank you, but there is one problem: if add  one more object to reports array like {comment:"asdasd", date:"12-02-2018", issueId:"1005"} (the date is day before yesterday), newArray will contain 6 elements, not 3 as expected.

Comment: You're right, and if you use the code I post, with one more condition, something like `for(let y = 0; y < newArray.length; y++){ if(newArray[y] != reports[x]){ ... } }` ? _I suggest I'm not a JS expert, I just want to help :)_

Answer (score 0):

> I am free to use ES5, ES6, underscore.js etc.

Using Ramda (http://ramdajs.com)

```
var duplicates = R.groupWith((a, b) => a.comment === b.comment && a.issueId === b.issueId, reports).filter(a => a.length > 1)
```